Given triangulated category $T$ with bounded t-structure, show that the heart generates $T$.
This question comes from Achar Appendix Chapter 7: Given triangulated category $\mathbf{T}$ with bounded t-structure $(\mathbf{T}^{\leq0},\mathbf{T}^{\geq0})$, show that the heart will generate $\mathbf{T}$ as a triangulated category.
I will confess, this is for a homework assignment. So please, if you do help, don't give the full answer. Any and all helpful hints are be greatly appreciated!
Some ideas that have come to mind: (i) Does $\text{Obj}(\mathbf{T})=\bigcup((\text{Obj(}\mathbf{T}^{\leq0})\cap(\text{Obj(}\mathbf{T}^{\geq0}))$? My immediate assumption is that it will not, otherwise the proof is very straight-forward. (ii) Are there any examples which might help to lead me down the right track? I've already seen the example with derived categories, though this doesn't feel too enlightening being that triangulated categories need not be abelian.
Thank you!
